# Prolog: Removing the duplicates of the merged list

Tags: prolog

I am doing a homework need to implement a relation list_merge (X,Y,Z) where X and Y are integer lists, Z contains all elements from both X and Y, and there is no duplicate in Z.

I know how to implement the append function and remove duplicates function.

append

```
append2([X|A],B,[X|C]):-!,append(A,B,C).
append2([],B,B).
```

remove duplicates

```
delete(X,[],[]).
delete(X,[X|T],R) :- delete(X,T,R).
delete(X,[H|T],[H|R]) :- not(X = H), delete(X,T,R).

remdups([],[]).
remdups([H|T],[H|R]) :- delete(H,T,S), remdups(S,R).
```

But I don't know how to combine these two releations in one relation so that I can remove the duplicates after merge the two lists. How can I combine the relations or any other methods which can have the same effect.

Some sample input and output:

```
?- list_merge([],[],L).
L = [].
?- list_merge([1],[1],L).
L = [1].
?- list_merge([],[1,3,1,1,1],L).
L = [1, 3] .
?- list_merge([5,3,1,2,1],[7,3,2,5,7],L).
L = [5, 7, 3, 2, 1] .
```

Comment: call remdups on the list returned by append

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner if the lists were ordered and you did a proper "merge" between them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, first append the two lists to an intermediate result, and the remove the duplicates from that intermediate result to get your final result.

```
list_merge(X, Y, Z) :-
    append2(X, Y, Z1),
    remdups(Z1, Z).
```